# FadeIn / FadeOut glitch using basic jQuery Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I'm working on a very **simple fadeIn / fadeOut tab system using jQuery**, however, it's not as smooth as I'd like it to be.

Here is my **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j4eFE/1/)** for you to see it in action.

Take a look at the demo. I expected it to fade in and out of one another, but if you click through **Tab 1 > Tab 2 > Tab 3** then back to **Tab 1**, there are strange fadeIn/Out glitches along the way.

Any ideas how I fix this?
My **jQuery** is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('ul.tabs').each(function(){

            var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

            $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
            $active.addClass('active');
            $content = $($active.attr('href'));

            $links.not($active).each(function () {
                $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
            });

            $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){

                $active.removeClass('active');
                $content.fadeOut("slow");

                $active = $(this);
                $content = $($(this).attr('href'));

                $active.addClass('active');
                $content.fadeIn("slow");

                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });

    });
```

and my **HTML** is:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab1">Overview</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Sub Nav 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Sub Nav 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="tab1">
    <p>this is a test 1</p>
</div>
<div id="tab2">
    <p>this is a test 2</p>
</div>
<div id="tab3">
    <p>this is a test 3</p>
</div>
```

Many thanks for any pointers :-)

Comment: Not a glitch lol, asynchronous. Just wait till the fadeOut is finished by using the callback: http://jsfiddle.net/j4eFE/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the code call back once its finished fading out.  Currently the code will execute the fade in before the fading out has completed. In order to cascade the call you can provide a function as the second parameter to [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).  This function will call immediately after the function has completed it's animation. In my case I provided an anonymous function that does the remaining code.

```
$content.fadeOut("slow", function()
                                 {
                                     $active = $(c);
                                     $content = $($(c).attr('href'));

                                     $active.addClass('active');
                                     $content.fadeIn("slow");
                                 });
```

I've updated you're fiddle. With the correct code modificiations.

http://jsfiddle.net/R8yQV/

Comment: That's absolutely fantastic!! Really appreciate your help with this. Time to learn some more jQuery I think :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to fade in and out on top of each other then you'll have to position them on top of each other. Otherwise they're positioned next to each other in the normal flow of the document so you're getting that strange looking behavior where the new item starts off to the side and then slides left when the disappearing item finally gets set to `display: none`. Try using `position: absolute` to position the items on top of each other. Then the fade in/out should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `div {float:left;}` in the css of your jsfiddle, use `div{position:absolute;}`
http://jsfiddle.net/j4eFE/11/

Using this your fadein and fadeout will occur simultaneously and will look very smooth.